# Is it correct to say "my ability is fully trained"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say "my ability is fully trained" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammatically, it is correct. Therefore, I guess you're asking if ability can be "fully trained".

From a dictionary we can see the definition of ability

> noun, plural abilities.
>
> 1. power or capacity to do or act physically, mentally, legally, morally, financially, etc.
> 2. competence in an activity or occupation because of one's skill, training, or other qualification:

And we can also look up the definition of train(ed)

> verb (used with object)
>
> 19. to make proficient by instruction and practice, as in some art, profession, or work:

Considering the definition of trained, and mostly the definition 2. of ability, you can see that this is valid. So yeah, it is correct to say "My ability is fully trained."

Comment: It may be grammatically correct (no argument from me on that point), but I think it's worth noting that it's not idiomatic speech, and it might strike some as an odd thing to say. Much more common would be: _I have been fully trained_, or perhaps: _I have completed all my training and I am able to do my job._

Comment: Ditto to @J.R. Saying *my ability is full trained* is grammatical makes me think of an old example by a student whose first language is the same as mine: *The fire is burning itself*. (No *out*)